# How to replace text of textView in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, textview, onclicklistener

I want to change a text of TextView on clicking a button. I have 2 buttons in my fragment and both have an `onClick` method for same TextView. Here is in detail what's happen in my fragment.

I set a default text to TextView means 1st text.
When 1st button clicked the 2nd text will appear on the TextView.
When 2nd button clicked again 1st text will appear on the TextView.

Here is my Fragment code

```js
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d("Rahul", "On Ganpati 1 fragment On Create ");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d("Rahul", "On Ganpati 1 fragment On Create View ");
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    final TextView textView = (TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.g1TextView);
    textView.setText(getString(R.string.Ganpati_1));

    Button marathi = (Button)getView().findViewById(R.id.g1Marathi);
    marathi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            textView.setText(getString(R.string.Ganpati_1));
        }
    });

    Button english = (Button)getView().findViewById(R.id.g1English);
    english.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            textView.setText(getString(R.string.GanpatiE));
        }
    });
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ganpati_1, container, false);
}
```

Here is the XML file

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.lenovo.shopping.Shankar">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="168dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Left"
        android:id="@+id/g1Marathi"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="168dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Right"
        android:id="@+id/g1English"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_gravity="right|top" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:paddingBottom="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_gravity="end|fill_vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/g1TextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/TextView" />

    </ScrollView>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: None of your Buttons or TextView ids appear to exist in the layout you provided.

Comment: You should also consider changing your onCreateView to start with View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ganpati_1, container, false); and returning the view object at the end of the method. That way you can use the inflated view to find the other objects. Such as Button marathi = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.left);

Comment: Thé view that is displayed is à new view without thé listeners. When you inflate de second time you recreate thé main view.

Comment: @lodlock thé ids are there.

Comment: They are now that it's been edited. You still want to move your inflation to the top and base your listeners off of the inflated view.

Comment: when i select this fragment from my expandable list view I get an error    FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                     at com.example.lenovo.shopping.Ganpati_1.onCreateView(Ganpati_1.java:44)
                                                     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962)

Comment: I just removed  the text and button code from the fragment and its working properly. Where should I have to set a text to my TextView in onCreate or In onCreateView?

Comment: You cannot call getView() in onCreateView!! It doesnt exist yet - you need to return it

Comment: So how can do?  please suggest me @Greg Ennis

Comment: You are trying to play with languages I guess. You should probably do this via values-en, value-ma ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When use **Fragment**, you need to override **onCreateView** and return **View** like this :

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ganpati_1, null);
    Log.d("Rahul", "On Ganpati 1 fragment On Create View ");
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    final TextView textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.g1TextView);
    textView.setText(getString(R.string.Ganpati_1));

    Button marathi = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.g1Marathi);

    marathi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        textView.setText(getString(R.string.Ganpati_1));
        }
    });

    Button english = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.g1English);
    english.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        textView.setText(getString(R.string.GanpatiE));
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

Comment: Is anyone have tutorials on the TextView please give me

Comment: Hi @RahulWaghmare, Please check android document http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html , i think it very clearly and useful

Comment: How to do the same from another method. Not from onCreateView, because that gets called only once.